# How to convert a list of tables into one big table in R

Tags: r, list, statistics, do.call

Using **R** ... I have a list of tables.

```
# Example data
z <- list(cbind(c(1,2), c(3,4)), cbind(c(1,2), c(3,4,5,6)), cbind(c(1,2), c(1,2,3,4,5,6)), cbind(c(1,2), c(3,4)), cbind(c(1,2), c(3,4,5,6,9,4,5,6)))
z <- setNames(z, c("Ethnicity", "Country", "Age Band", "Marital Status", "Hair Color"))

z

$Ethnicity
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4

$Country
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4
[3,]    1    5
[4,]    2    6

$`Age Band`
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    2    2
[3,]    1    3
[4,]    2    4
[5,]    1    5
[6,]    2    6

$`Marital Status`
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4

$`Hair Color`
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4
[3,]    1    5
[4,]    2    6
[5,]    1    9
[6,]    2    4
[7,]    1    5
[8,]    2    6
```

I would like to "collapse" (not sure if that is the right word) this list into one super table, as the column variables are the same for every table in the list. I would want the output to look something like that which I have written below... Is there any way to do this? I tried using `do.call(rbind, z)` but this didn't give me the proper output.

```
Ethnicity
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4
Country
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4
[3,]    1    5
[4,]    2    6
`Age Band`
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    2    2
[3,]    1    3
[4,]    2    4
[5,]    1    5
[6,]    2    6
`Marital Status`
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4
`Hair Color`
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4
[3,]    1    5
[4,]    2    6
[5,]    1    9
[6,]    2    4
[7,]    1    5
[8,]    2    6
```

Comment: `do.call(rbind, z)` creates one big table. The only difference is that it doesn't retain the table names in your example output. What is your intended use? You might just be looking for a special way to print it.

Comment: Right, I want to keep the names for each subsection intact.

Comment: And do what with it? Just print it out?

Comment: Yeah I have about 1,000 tables in my list and I was going to literally copy/paste the entire thing into Excel like that and then use the text import wizard to bring it in

Comment: That sounds suboptimal. Why don't you write what you need to a text file? Also, why would you want this in Excel if you have it nicely in R?

Comment: Well, to prepare a big table to paste into my manuscript. Haha, perhaps suboptimal. That's how i usually operate

Comment: How would I just write the whole thing to a text file? I tried write.table() but it gave me an error: Error in data.frame(UserID = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L,  : arguments imply differing number of rows:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This produces your desired output if I understand it correctly:

```
sink("output.txt")
for (i in seq_along(z)) {
  cat(names(z)[i], '\n') # print out the header
  write.table(z[[i]], row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
}
sink()
```

I open a connection to a text file with `sink` then loop over your list of tables and print each one out using `write.table`.

It produces the following output:

```
Ethnicity 
1 3
2 4
Country 
1 3
2 4
1 5
2 6
Age Band 
1 1
2 2
1 3
2 4
1 5
2 6
...
```